# Weird behavior while using numba on a raspberry pi zero

Tags: python, numba, jit, raspberry-pi-zero

I got some weird behavior while using numba on a raspberry pi zero. When I use floating numbers, my function returns weird calculations which are mathematically wrong. This is my code:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def numtesting(n):
    print(n)
    print(n)


numtesting(1.0)
```

I would expect

- 1.0
- 1.0

Instead i get:

- 1.0
- 0.031326431754716

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: What happens without `@numba`?

Comment: i get an error, that jit is not known. When i use `from numba import jit` I get the same results. And without the decorator I get the expected behavior: `1.0 1.0`

Comment: I mean comment out that line to turn this into regular Python code as a baseline.

Comment: Commenting out the decorator or deleting it will provide the expected result: `1.0 1.0`

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in the ARM version of the JIT? I'd consider reporting it if you can reproduce this easily enough with this code.

Comment: Good idea, i reported it here: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up installing numba on my Raspberry Pi Zero. Found infos on github that numba only correctly works on 64-bit architectures. However, I bought myself a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 with 64-bit architecture and I managed to install numba 0.56.4 on it. However, I had to use some workarounds, here is how i did it:

OS: Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32bit)
For llvmlite to be installed successfully, I installed `sudo apt install -y llvm-dev libffi-dev`
For numpy to run successfully, I installed `sudo apt-get install -y libatlas libopenjp2-7`
After that i used `pip install llvmlite==0.39.1` into a virtual environment
At this point I faced the issue, that the installer froze builing a wheel for llvmlite. ChatGPT helped by recommending to increase the SWAP size in `/etc/dphys-swapfile` to 1024 (Default was 100). The parameter is called `CONF_SWAPSIZE`

After that i was able to install numpy into my virtual environment using `pip install numpy==0.56.4`
I really hope it helps someone. I took me quite some time to figure this out...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).